# Set Node Add Form Title Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to set a custom title for a node add form in drupal and for some reason it does absolutely nothing, my code in my template.php file is:

```
function templatename_form_alter($form_id, &$form)
{
    if ($form_id == 'contenttypename_node_form') {
        drupal_set_title('my custom title');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add on to this, the above method works great, however if a user edits a node it will shoe the specified title as well, to further this item put

```
function yourtheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'contenttype_node_form':
      if ($form['nid']['#value'] != '') {
        drupal_set_title("Edit " . $form['title']['#default_value']);
      }
      else {
        drupal_set_title("Your name.");
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The parameters for [`hook_form_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) in Drupal 6-8 are `&$form, &$form_state, $form_id`. You're using the Drupal 5 form of `$form_id, &$form`.

So what you want is this:

```
 function yourtheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   switch ($form_id) {
   case 'contenttype_node_form':
     drupal_set_title("Your title.");
     break;
   }
 }
```